# implicit datatyping no longer working in oracle 11g

Tags: sql, tomcat, oracle11g

We have been noticing since we upgraded tomcat from 7.0.28 to 7.0.40 that implicit datatyping in oracle sql is not working the same way that it used to.  An Example of sql that used to execute just fine...but now throws an error...

sql = "select * from match_table where dec = ? ";

Table structure...

```
COLUMN_NAME         DATA_TYPE       NULLABLE
JOB_CD              VARCHAR2(10)    Yes         
DEC                 NUMBER          Yes         
MATCH_KEY           VARCHAR2(70)    Yes




     Connection conn = null;
     PreparedStatement pst = null;
     ResultSet rs = null;
     int inserted =0;
        try {
            conn = BasicDataSourceManager.getConnection();
            pst = conn.prepareStatement( sql );
            pst.setString(1,dropDecInfo.getDec() );
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
        }catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

....dropDecInfo.getDec() returns the dec code as a string.

This code used to work on a tomcat server ....but now I get ...ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

If I run this on the same linux box ....as batch java (from a class with a valid main) from a shell script it works fine.  We are getting similar errors with date fields that aren't explicitly cast using to_date. We are using Oracle 11g with ojdbc14-10.2.0.0.jar.

Comment: Well, then it is an ojdbc issue, not a tomcat issue specifically.  try selecting each column individually to see which one is the problem.  Also, why does your DEC field not have a size specifier on it?  Seems strange.

Comment: Are you certain that `dropDecInfo.getDec()` is returning a string that can be implicitly converted to a `number` (i.e. there are no non-numeric characters in the string)?  Is the query really as simple as the one you posted?  The error you're posting would be much more common if you were, say, joining to another table where there was a `varchar2` column that was storing (mostly) numeric data.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of implicit date cast indicates that the two systems, which act as an Oracle client, use different NLS settings that affect the date format. The implicit conversion fails because the date is parsed with a date format that doesn't match the format in your database (or vice versa).

The same could have happened to the implicit number conversion.

The Oracle OJDBC drivers initialize the NLS settings using some rules that query the language setting of the Java environment, which is derived from the OS environment. So the Tomcat startup script could have caused the change.

To fix it, try to explicitly set either in the Java environment or by appropriately initializing each Oracle connection.